# Binary Search Tree - Javascript - Distance between two nodes

Tags: binary-search-tree

Given a Binary Search Tree and two nodes, n1 and n2, write a function that finds the distance between the two nodes.

Example: The distance between the nodes 4 and 10 is 4. The distance between the nodes 8 and 10 is 1. The distance between the nodes 1 and 14 is 4.

```
class Node {
constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
   constructor() {
     this.root = null;
}
```

So far this is all I have, am not sure how to go about finding the distance between nodes.

Comment: Please attempt to calculate the distance by yourself first, and include that attempt in the question